# Sending messages for processing

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class which is responsible for waiting until a message is added to a message list and then sending it off to get processed.

- `withdrawMessages` waits for a message. I wait for a total of 2 minutes for a message to appear. I do this to keep the connection alive on my browser.
- `depositMessage` adds a message to the message list.

The process flow I am aiming for is:

- Deposit a message into the list
- Wait is notified and the whole list gets passed to the processor object (`IUpdater`)

If `processMessages` is about to get executed and a new message is added to the list I want to make sure this new message is also sent when calling `responseUpdater.sendResponse`

I need it to be thread-safe so when `responseUpdater.sendResponse(messageList);` is actually getting processed, then nothing else can be added to the list. It needs to wait until `sendResponse` is completed before adding it.

`sendResponse` basically sends the list to browser then the browser sends back a request to call `withdrawMessages`. So if a new message is added when `sendResponse` is getting executed, it has to wait until `withdrawMessages` is called again. At that point it will process the messages.

```
public class MessagePusher {

    private static final int TWO_MINUTE_WAIT = 120 * 1000;
    private volatile boolean notified = false;
    private final ArrayList<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private void waitOnMessages(int duration) throws InterruptedException {
        messageList.wait(duration);
    }

    private void notifyWaitingThreads() {
        if (messageList.size() > 0) {
            notified = true;
            this.messageList.notify();
        }
    }

    public void depositMessage(String message) {
        synchronized (this.messageList) {
            this.messageList.add(message);
            notifyWaitingThreads();
        }
    }

    //IUpdater just processes the messages
    public void withdrawMessages(IUpdater updater) {
        boolean processRequired = false;
        synchronized (messageList) {
            //gets lock
            boolean timeout = false;
            try {
                //releases lock
                waitOnMessages(TWO_MINUTE_WAIT);
                //gets lock again
                if ((!notified)) {
                    timeout = true;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                ShipsLog.out.asWarning("Unexpected exception! Nested exception is:\n" + e);
            }
            if (notified || timeout) {
                notified = false;
                processRequired = true;
            }
        }
        if (processRequired) {
            processMessages(updater);
        }
    }

    public void processMessages(IUpdater responseUpdater) {
            synchronized (messageList) {
                responseUpdater.sendResponse(messageList);
                messageList.clear();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like you only have one lock, so you can't have deadlock; but for future reference, you can add deadlock detection to the program, see for example [this blog post](http://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/deadlock-detection-in-java/) but there are many other options available.
2. You may want to replace the arraylist with a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), this will let you remove the synchronized block from `depositMessage` and may let you remove the synchronized block from `withdrawMessages` and `processMessages` depending on how `responseUpdater.sendReponse` is implemented.  In general, try to use lock-free data structures when possible - they generally scale better, and you can't heave deadlock if you don't have any locks.
3. [ConTest](https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/verification/contest/index.html) is a tool for detecting multithreading problems e.g. race conditions.  [Java Pathfinder](http://javapathfinder.sourceforge.net/) is a much more heavyweight approach to this.
4. For a large project, you may want to use a library like [Akka](http://akka.io/) or [JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/) to manage concurrency.